# TailwindCSS & NextJS - Different color mode than Dark

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

According to TailwindCSS Docs, you can specify color mode by `document.body.addClass('dark')` and use it on your CSS classnames like `dark:text-blue-500`.

But there is no option for adding new color modes, i want something like  `evening`, `midnight`. Any ideas how to implement different color modes without going too much into it?

The most logical way i can think is create a `ColorModeContext` and export my components according to context but it is kinda hardcoded.

Answer (score 4):

Tailwind 3.1 now includes [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) which, along with the [addVariant plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#creating-a-plugin), can be used to create custom color modes. Using the [css * selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors), you can apply a class like `evening` to an element, and all its children will have apply `evening: ...` styles.

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
let plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin")

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('evening', '.evening *')
      addVariant('midnight', '.midnight *')
    })
  ]
}
```

`pages/[some-page].jsx`

```html
<div className="evening">
    <div className="text-blue-300 evening:text-blue-500"></div>
</div>
```